# Use another module in our custom helper in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, factory, helper, servicemanager

I want to use WebinoImageThumb moudle in my custom helper , but when I want to create an instance of this module in helper factories I got this error :

```
Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for WebinoImageThumb
```

But I can access to an instance in my controller without any problem.

This is the code I get error in :

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' =>  array(
            'ImageLib' => function ($sm)
            {
                $WebinoImageThumb = $sm->get('WebinoImageThumb');
               return new \Base\view\helper\ImageLib($WebinoImageThumb);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question that's left out is: What kind of entry is `WebinoImageThumb`. Is it a **ViewHelper**, is it a **ControllerPlugin** or is it a **Service**?

It probably **isn't a ViewHelper**, because if it would be, you could access it like you did.

If it's a **Service**, you'll get it from the ServiceManager

```
return new \Base\View\Helper\ImageLib(
    $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('WebinoImageThumb')
);
```

If it's a **ControllerPlugin**, you'll get it from the `ControllerPluginManager`

```
return new \Base\View\Helper\ImageLib(
    $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('WebinoImageThumb')
);
```