# How do I call the getServiceLocator in Model ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to call getServiceLocator in model method but it is throwing below error
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Actually, I am using $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config'); in model which result the above fatal error

Comment: The error means you're trying to execute a function on not-an-object. You also must show code for us to be able to say anything more.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the ServiceLocator in a model class. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858171/1644937, or just search in google for: "service locator antipattern" to get tons of arguments against this practice.

Answer (score 0):

You coun't not use directly the ServiceLocator in a model class but if you want to use `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');` on model then

`$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');` Assign in controller and pass the $config in madel

```
$ModelTable->searchList($data, $config);
```

now you call/use any method/function of config.

Comment: I know I can do this way but I don't want to follow this approach. Looking something inbuilt to use getServiceLocator directly into model.